# P-trivial $\sigma-$algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to proof the following:

Consider an probability space with a P-trivial $\sigma-$Algebra $G$. Show that for any real-valued $G$-measurable random variable $X$, there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that$X=c$ almost surely.

My idea:

Considering cdf implies: $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t) \in \{0,1\}$

Hence $G$ is trivial, there is $x_0 := \inf\{x: F_X(x)=1\}$. Thus $P(X=x_0)= F_X(x_0)- \lim_{x<x_0} F_X(x)=1$.

Therefore $X$ is constant. But why does this hold almost surely?

Comment: By P-trivial $\sigma$-algebra do you mean it only contains the empty and the whole set?

Comment: @MilosTasic: Sorry I mean for each set $A  \subset G \ P(A )\in \{0,1\} $

Comment: $P(X=x_0)=1$ means $X$ is equal to the constant $x_0$ almost surely.

Comment: I believe there is a slight gap in your argument.  For your $\ x_0\ $ to be a well-defined element of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $  the set $\ \big\{x:F_X(x)=1\big\}\ $ has to be non-empty and bounded below.  While this is  not difficult to show, I believe it's something you need to do to make your argument watertight.  Then [Kavi Rama Murthy's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy) observation gives you your conclusion.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Now I see. Sorry:)

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: Why does the set has to be bounded from below?

Comment: @Tom If the set is not bounded from below it has no infimum—not, at least,  a real valued infimum. In the *extended reals* its infimum would be $\ -\infty\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: How can I see that? I am not quite sure.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please,  upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is essentially correct. It needs just a small adjustments. Here is a detailed proof, using your argument.

Consider $F_X(t)$  for $t$ in the extended real line, $\overline{\Bbb R}= \Bbb R \cup \{-\infty , +\infty\}$.

Then $F_X(+\infty)=P(X\leq +\infty) =1$, and so let $c := \inf \{x\in \overline{\Bbb R} : F_X(x)=1\}$.

**Claim**: $F_X(c) = 1$.

In fact, since $c := \inf \{x\in \overline{\Bbb R} : F_X(x)=1\}$, there is a decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in  $\{x\in \overline{\Bbb R} : F_X(x)=1\}$, such that $x_n \to c$. So
$$F_X(c) = P(X\leq c) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P(X\leq x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} F_X(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1=1$$
(You can also see the claim is true, directly from the fact that $F_X$ is continuous from the right.)

Now, $P(X=c)= F_X(c)- \lim_{x \to a^{-}} F_X(x)=1$.

So, $P(X \neq c)=0$, which means that $X=c$ almost surely.

**Remark**: Note that we can not conclude that $\{x: X(x) \neq c\} =\emptyset$. So we can not conclude that $X=c$. We can only conclude that $P(X \neq c)=0$, that is why we have $X=c$ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is there a decreasing sequence $x_n \rightarrow c$?

Comment: The rest is perfect for me:)

Comment: @Tom , $c := \inf \{x\in \overline{\Bbb R} : F_X(x)=1\}$. It is a property of the $\inf$, that there is a decreasing sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in  $\{x\in \overline{\Bbb R} : F_X(x)=1\}$, such that $x_n \to c$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.